# How to adjust phone number to same format?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to extract data from my database, and I wish the when I extract the data all the h/p number all is same format.

sample:

+60161234567
016-1234567
0161234567

To:
+6016-1234567

Answer (score 1):

The following simple code will give you the expected Output.

```
SELECT 
(CASE 
   WHEN contact_number RLIKE "^[+]([0-9]){10}" THEN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(contact_number,1,5), "-", SUBSTRING(contact_number,6,7))
   WHEN contact_number RLIKE "^([0-9]){3}[-]([0-9]){7}" THEN CONCAT("+6",contact_number)
   WHEN contact_number RLIKE "^([0-9]){10}" THEN CONCAT("+6",SUBSTRING(contact_number,1,3), "-", SUBSTRING(contact_number,4,7))
   ELSE 'Number is not in correct format'
END) AS 'Phone Number'
FROM table_name;
```

We have to use the regular expression for checking number format. I have done the query based on the number format that you have given. If a different format is there then try corresponding regular expression.

In the query, the 1st case for the number like "+60161234567", the 2nd case for the number like "016-1234567" and Last case for the number like "0161234567".

I have attached my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d71398/1) to this solution. You can check it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat and substr function to change format of phone number column during extracting data as below:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(SUBSTR( contact_number, 1, 5 ) ,  "-", SUBSTR( contact_number, 5 ) ) AS phone_no FROM test_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT("+6",SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone, '+6', ''), '-', ''),1,3), "-", SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(phone, '+6', ''), '-', ''),4,7)) FROM `phone`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that an h/p number is a phone number?

This isn't a number, in the data type sense, so it shouldn't be stored as one. Numbers can have math applied to them and represent some finite value. Varchar or char is probably the appropriate data type here. When inserting the data, standardize the way you record the data and fix it in your application before inserting. In the US, phone numbers can be shown as `(555) 123-4567` or `555-123-4567` so you could just pick the format — or what I would do is store it as `5551234567` and then format it in the application when displaying it to the user (that way, the user can prefer one format or the other). At the minimum, though, you should standardize the format when inserting the string so that you don't have to deal later with a variety of formats.

For data that already exists, I think your best bet is to fix the whole database. I would use some programming or scripting language that's good at manipulating data to fix it in the database (personally I think Python is a good choice).